# Strange coincidences about ec primes

Tags: number-theory

Ec primes are primes of the form:

$(2^n-1)\cdot 10^d+2^{n-1}-1$, where d Is the Number of decimal digits of $2^{n-1}$.

I have found this:

$92020, 331259, 75894, 56238$ are n's leading to a probable prime.

Now I notice that:

$\underbrace {92020+239239}_{331259}\equiv 71\cdot 6^4+4+239239\equiv 1\equiv 56238+75894\equiv 132132 \pmod{1861\cdot 71}$.

Is that a coincidence?

Which Is the meaning of all this? Nothing? Or Is it a clear evidence of a mega-structure underlying these exponents? Is It $1861$ too arbitrary? Who knows?

Is It all this connected to the fact that there are exponents leading to an ec prime which are congruent to $-72\pmod {1001}$ like $92020$ and $331259$

Comment: If I had to bet , my money would be on "it is another case of the law of small numbers". Since we can expect infinite many ec-primes (heuristic arguments indicate that , but of course a proof will be almost surely out of reach) , somewhere in huge ranges , such coincidences can repeat.

Comment: But probably this would just be another coincidence. The structure of those numbers is complicated , we cannot even classify the exponents for which ec(n) is divisible by $7$.