# Ec primes multiple of 67 and $1\pmod{67}$

Tags: recreational-mathematics, conjectures

Ec primes are primes of the form:

$(2^n-1)\cdot 10^d+2^{n-1}-1=ec(n)$, where d Is the Number of decimal digits of $2^{n-1}$.

I conjecture that there are infinitely many primes of this form with n either $\equiv 0\pmod {67}$ or $\equiv 1\pmod {67}$

Verification: for $n=67, 6231,51456, 79798, 285019$ $ec(n)$ is probable prime.
Is that another coincidence or law of small numbers?

The multiples of $67$, that Is 6231 and 51456 are also multiple of 3.
And $79797$, $285018$  are divisible by 3 too. Is there a particular reason?

$79797=201\cdot 397$ Is a palindromic Number Just a curio.

Comment: Please ask one question per post, so that potential answerers can focus. (Well, two closely related questions, or one rather simple question with a hard follow-up question, or a similar constellation... could be accepted, it is all about progress, understanding and learning on this site). In this case, we have a definition of EC-primes with no reference. Similar questions are already on this site, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4798332/strange-coincidences-about-ec-primes for instance, closed for clarity reasons. Here there is (for me) also a clarity problem. What is a "coincidence"?

Comment: Also, we have a conjecture for a situation that cannot be attacked with structural weapons. In the second when we take $d$ to be the number of decimal digits of some power of two, we leave number theory and go in a human patchwork situation lacking any importance. Then the number $67$ enters the dance floor. We have a "verification" with five cases for a conjecture on infinitely many prime numbers, that a second person cannot verify, but rather accept when we redefine prime to be a probable prime. (Which is maybe an integer number without factors smaller $10^{100}$ maybe.)

Comment: @dan_fulea I agree with the comments apart from the probable-prime-issue , although purely theoretically the primes would have to be proven prime. But here we are in the topic recreational mathematics where the "probable primes" have an established meaning. The main issue is that we are limited to heuristics because we soon arrive at magnitudes of numbers too big to even apply a PRP-test.